# How to store selected multiple checkbox values in an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

```
<input type="checkbox"name="travel[]" value="bus"/>
<input type="checkbox"name="travel[]" value="train"/>
<input type="checkbox"name="travel[]" value="plane"/>
foreach($_POST['travel']as $selected)
  var select[]=$selected;
```

If the user selects all the three checkboxes, I have to store them in an array and send it to mail as I dont have a data base. So how should I store them in an array?

```
foreach($_POST['travel']as $selected)
var select[]=$selected;
```

The above code is returning only last selected check box
And how should I pass it and display it on the mail?

Comment: your `$_POST['travel']` is already an array

Comment: No need of `foreach`  because  your `$_POST['travel']` is itself an array with that 3 selected value use that directly.thanks.

Comment: There should be a space between checkbox"name.
$html='You selected '; foreach($_POST['travel']as $selected) $html.=$selected." ";

Comment: I am not sure you excpeted this is `var select = implode(",",$_POST['travel']);` now you get the value using `{{select}}` in mail template its returns `bus,train`

Comment: Thank you sathish. what is the difference between var selcet and $select?can I use $select = implode(",",$_POST['travel']);

Comment: @raga yes then assign `var select = $select`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
foreach($_POST['travel']as $selected)
var select[]=$selected;
```

update it to

```
$select = array();
foreach($_POST['travel'] as $key => $selected){
    $select[$key]=$selected;
}
```

Instead of using `foreach` simply use `$select = implode(',',$_POST['travel']);`

Comment: it is correct answer. why down-voted.? people are insane. i up-voted to you.

Comment: Even I don't know whats the reason behind the downvoting. Anyways thanks @anantkumarsingh

Answer (score 0):

Because every time you are defining a new array, by `var select[]=$selected;`.

Change it it `$select[]=$selected;`

Answer (score 0):

please give different names as below.
after posting data using foreach loop you will get all selected options
`<input type="checkbox" name="travel1[]" value="bus"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="travel2[]" value="train"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="travel3[]" value="plane"/>`